# my query is taking a long time to execute

Tags: php, mysql

I have following query .. in Dev_phones I have 90 000 item in Dev_users 50 000

```
select `u`.`id` from `Dev_users` as `u`
left join `Dev_user_usergroup_map` as `m` on `u`.`id` = `m`.`user_id` 
left join `Dev_phones` as `p` on `m`.`id` = `p`.`acc_id` and `primary`=1 
where  `u`.`email`='sample@gmail.com' or `u`.`private_number`='sample@gmail.com'  
or  `m`.`id`='sample@gmail.com' or `p`.`number`='sample@gmail.com' limit 1
```

query goes to loop and not ending ... 
what is problem and how can i write better this query

Comment: So what indexes do you have on your tables? have you run an EXPLAIN against the query? (if so, what did it say)

Comment: I fixed a quote `or  \`m\`.\`id\`` was written as `or  'm\`.\`id\``. I think this was a paste/type error?

Comment: No this is not issue ... I'm running the query and cpu of server goes 100% and finally i'm getting ngix timeout

Comment: Definitely do what Mark has suggested. I'd bet that the LEFT JOINs are the culprit. In this scenario, I think MySQL will be doing a row-by-row WHERE comparison on 90,000 * 50,000 * <Dev_user_usergroup_map row count> rows

Comment: @Mihai since it is an `or` condition, a composed index won't do the trick. Two separate indexes are better.

Comment: It's a little odd to OUTER JOIN tables from which you select no columns - but then the WHERE/OR condition sort of renders them as INNER JOINs anyway. All a bit strange - and note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless (although I suppose "LIMIT 1" is an exception)

Comment: Can you write query as answer ?

Comment: @strawberry, since it is an `or` condition, they don't actually work as an inner join, since a condition like `p.number='sample@gmail.com'` will be ignored if any of the previous conditions is already true. Can you explain what you mean that limit is meaningless? It limits the result to a spoecified number of rows. This happens with or without `order by`, although it is a bit more random without it, but that applies to `limit 1` as much as to any other number.

Comment: @GolezTrol You might use "LIMIT 1" to mean "EXISTS". "LIMIT any other number" is theoretically meaningless because, technically, returned row order is unpredictable. Oh, and if they *don't* work as an INNER JOIN then that comes back to my point about selecting no columns from those tables!

Comment: you need query to finish off and showing the results? try to use group by just for try. I was with this issue a time ago and it solve by grouping results instead of creating all joins in new rows and returning the first one. The problem was that he try to join all columns before set limit 1, for 90k~50~ with OR conditions is all normal that’s take a long time, but it need to return a result instead, if not work just go ahead.

Comment: If you just want 5 rows max, you can add LIMIT without ORDER BY. It might speed up the query where adding ORDER BY slows it down again. I can think of use cases for that, for instance showing recommended products related to a given product. You might have dozens products that could be displayed, but you only want to show a couple, no matter which ones.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, this query can be rewritten as follows - although I find using OUTER JOIN with OR (or an IN) across several tables in this way very confusing...

```
SELECT u.id 
  FROM Dev_users u
  LEFT
  JOIN Dev_user_usergroup_map m 
    ON u.id = m.user_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN Dev_phones p 
    ON m.id = p.acc_id 
   AND `primary` = 1 
 WHERE 'sample@gmail.com' IN(u.email,u.private_number,m.id,p.number)
 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Moving the conditions to the joins might make it faster (I was going to suggest trying this), but the `samplemail in` condition in the `where` clause is a bit confusing to me.